# histogram not working properly on pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I'm trying to use the built-in plotting methods of pandas dataframe objects but I'm having trouble with groupby. Observe the following, this first code section works as expected.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['D'] = np.random.randint(0, 3, len(df))
df.A.plot(kind='hist', histtype='stepfilled')
```

[image: Properly interpreted histogram plot]

Now see what happens when I try it with a groupby object

```
dfg = df.groupby('D')
dfg.A.plot(kind='hist', histtype='stepfilled')
```

[image: Does not perform histogram]

The result is a standard plot. It doesn't appear to take any options. When I try to just use the .hist() method it won't accept or process the keywords.

```
 dfg.A.hist(histtype='stepfilled')
```

[image: Does not pass through keywords]

Am I doing something wrong? Should I file a bug report? Or am I expecting something that isn't intended to be provided?

Comment: I think this should be a pandas github issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the following instead of `groupby`:

```
df.A.plot(kind='hist', by='D', histtype='stepfilled')
```

This returns something like:

[image]

Actually I think that a `groupby` object doesn't work properly with the plotting functions, you have to use the `by` keyword. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'd seen the "by" keyword, but was never sure how to use it. However, I'm not sure what that's doing here. That looks like it's probably generating the same plot as my first one. It's not separating it out into the groups organized by column "D". Also, I wonder if it would work for more advanced groupby's, such as ranges of values.